# Find the Radius, Central Angle, and Arc Length Given Sector Area and Perimeter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

The question is as follows:

> There is a circular sector that has a 33-inch perimeter and that encloses an area of 54-inch. Find its central angle, radius, and arc length, rounding to the nearest tenth.

I know the following ratios:
$$\frac{\text{Area of Sector}}{\text{Area of Circle}} = \frac{\text{Central Angle}}{360^{\circ}} = \frac{\text{Sector Length}}{\text{Circumference of Circle}}$$

And if I substitute the values that I know for this problem, then I get: $$\frac{{54\text{in.} ^2}}{\pi r^2 } = \frac{\text{Central Angle}}{360^{\circ}} = \frac{\text{Sector Length}}{2\pi r }$$

I am aware that this ratio is not incorporating the perimeter of the sector, but I do not know how to do that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that your unit fir the area is wrong. Maybe square inches?

Comment: @geo_freak Do you still need help?